# fill combobox with cells that contain #

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

I'm trying to fill a combobox with cells from column A that contain #. I get an error message: "Couldn't find specific object." Please help me understand what I'm missing here. Thank you.

```
        Dim i As Long
        Dim lr As Long

        Sheets("Colon").Select
        lr = Worksheets("Colon").Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lr
            If InStr(Cells(i, 1).Value, "#") > 0 Then

                ComboBox1.List = Worksheets(1).Range("A2:A" & lr).Value
                UserForm1.Controls("ComboBox" & i).Object.List = ComboBox1.List

            End If

        Next i
```

Comment: What is the line of the code with problem??? I guess you cannot use "A" in cells, you must use 1.

Comment: Also, do you have many comboboxes? `Combobox & i`? Sounds like you are adding the entire column `Range("A2:A" & lr)` to the list, and then adding the same thing to a lot of lists. Maybe you just need List.Add with `Range("A" & lr).value`

Comment: I get an error @ `UserForm1.Controls("ComboBox" & i).Object.List = ComboBox1.List
Thanks

Comment: Where do I need to put List.Add with `Range("A" & lr).value`? Please be more specific. I only have one combobox "ComboBox1".

Comment: Do you have any `Combobox2` or `Combobox3`? Those are the objects it cannot find

Comment: I only have Combobox1, which I'm trying to fill with values from column A but  only if they contain  a #.  Sorry...

Comment: That's why it doesn't work. `("Combobox" & i)` is asking for combobox1, combobox2, combobox3. Those elements do not exist, thus the error "could not find specific object".

Answer (score 0):

Here, I got one for you. Try with this.

```
Public Sub fillCombo()

    Dim row, lastRow, index As Long
    Dim dataList() As String

    'Data list index
    index = 0

    'Getting the last row
    lastRow = Sheets("Colon").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

    'Looping all row from row 2.
    For row = 2 To lastRow

        'Here, my logic is some cell value which not include "#" are not store in array.
        'If "#" is include in cell value.
        If InStr(Cells(row, 1).Value, "#") > 0 Then

            'Increase index
            index = index + 1

            'Re-declare dataList size
            ReDim Preserve dataList(index)

            'Store cell value in array
            dataList(index) = Cells(row, 1).Value

        End If

    Next row

    'Set dataList to combo box.
    Sheets("Colon").ComboBox1.List = dataList

End Sub
```